# Issues with dual-pane preference screens

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

**Problem**
Rotating a device from a one-pane portrait `PreferenceScreen` to a two-pane landscape `PreferenceScreen`, causes landscape to only show as one-pane. Does NOT occur when viewing the headers screen.

**Setup**
This is for ICS and up only. I have a `PreferenceActivity` which loads `preference-headers`. Each header links with a `Fragment`, which in turn loads a `PreferenceScreen`. Pretty run of the mil.

**Details**
Everything worked well until I noticed that Android will only auto-switch to a two-pane look for certain screens. After some research I learned from a [Commonsware post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/10/16/conditional-preference-headers.html) that Android will only do so for sw720dp. Bit of a waste if you ask me since many devices def have plenty of room for two-panes.  So I overrided the `onIsMultiPane()` method to return true for w600dp and up.  Worked like a charm....kinda.

Given a device which will show single-pane in portrait and dual-pane in landscape; viewing the headers in portrait and rotating to landscape, works fine.  However if one selects a header and loads it's subsequent screen in portrait mode, then rotate to landscape the device will stay single-pane instead of switching back to dual-pane. If you then back navigate to the headers screen, it'll return to a dual-pane look except that it won't pre-select a header. As a result the detailed pane stays blank.

Is this intended behavior? Anyway to work around it?  I tried overriding `onIsHidingHeaders()` as well but that just caused everything to show a blank screen.

**Code**
Preference Activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    super.onBuildHeaders(target);
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference, target);
}

@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_prefer_dual_pane);
}
}
```

A Preference Header Frag:

```
public class ExpansionsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_expansions);
}

public static ExpansionsFragment newInstance() {
    ExpansionsFragment frag = new ExpansionsFragment();

    return frag;
}
}
```

Comment: What "say" a debug perspective?

Comment: You have a values which contains state "visible" i mean.

Comment: PreferenceActivity handles the visibility changes. I'm specifically not altering any of that.  The above code is literally all I am doing.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid activity destruction and recreation by using this in your manifest: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"? If so, then that might be the cause. The reason I suspect this is because when you change orientation Android should rebuild your activity from the ground up but it seems like it isn't here. It's just something to check I guess.

Comment: Nope. I'm not overriding the config changes. Considering the lack of answers, I just choose to use preferences as normal.

Comment: Might it be that there's a something in a resource folder with a -sw720p suffix that's causing a different layout file/different style attribute/similar to be used instead?

Comment: Try using "UnifiedPreference", a library which simplifies the usage of 'PreferenceActivity':
https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference

Comment: lets see the xml for the two preference files

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**
With how popular this question has become, I decided to revisit this issue again and see if I could find a resolution...and I did.  Found a nice little work around that solves the single pane showing instead of dual pane and ensuring a header is always pre-selected when in dual pane mode.

If you don't care about an explanation, you can just skip on down to the code.  If you don't care about ICS, a lot of the header tracking code can be removed as JB added a getter for the headers array list.

**Dual Pane Issue**
When viewing the preference header list in single pane mode or dual pane mode, there is only ever one PreferenceActivity created and it's the same activity for both cases. As a result, there's never a problem in handling screen rotations that will switch the pane mode.

However, in single pane mode when you click on a header, the corresponding fragment is attached to a NEW PreferenceActivity.  This new fragment containing PreferenceActivity never invokes `onBuildHeaders()`.  And why would it? It doesn't need to display them.  This lie ins the problem.

When rotating that fragment into a dual pane mode, it doesn't have any header list to show so it just continues to show the fragment only. Even if it did show the header's list, you'll have some backstack issues as you would now have two copies of the PreferenceActivity showing headers. Keep clicking enough headers and you'll get quite a lengthy stack of activities for the user to navigate back through. As a result, the answer is simple.  Just `finish()` the activity.  It'll then load the original PreferenceActivity which DOES have the header list and will properly show the dual pane mode.

**Auto Selecting Header**
The next issue that needed tackling was that switching between single to dual pane mode with the new fix didn't auto select a header. You were left with a headers list and no details fragment loaded.  This fix isn't quite as simple.  Basically you just have to keep track of which header was last clicked and ensure during PreferenceActivity creation...a header is always selected.

This ends up being a bit annoying in ICS since the API does not expose a getter for the internally tracked headers list.  Android does already persist that list and you could technically retrieve it by using the same privately stored internal string key however that's just a bad design choice.  Instead, I suggest manually persisting it again yourself.

If you don't care about ICS, then you can just use the `getHeaders()` method exposed in JB and not worry about any of this saved/restore state stuff.

**Code**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
private static final String STATE_CUR_HEADER_POS = "Current Position";
private static final String STATE_HEADERS_LIST   = "Headers List";

private int mCurPos = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;  //Manually track selected header position for dual pane mode
private ArrayList<Header> mHeaders;  //Manually track headers so we can select one. Required to support ICS.  Otherwise JB exposes a getter instead.

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference, target);
    mHeaders = (ArrayList<Header>) target;  //Grab a ref of the headers list
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //This is the only code required for ensuring a dual pane mode shows after rotation of a single paned preference screen
    if (onIsMultiPane() && onIsHidingHeaders()) {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    //Override this if you want dual pane to show up on smaller screens
    return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_prefer_dual_pane);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //Intercept a header click event to record its position.
    mCurPos = position;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    //Retrieve our saved header list and last clicked position and ensure we switch to the proper header.
    mHeaders = state.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_HEADERS_LIST);
    mCurPos = state.getInt(STATE_CUR_HEADER_POS);
    if (mHeaders != null) {
        if (mCurPos != AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            switchToHeader(mHeaders.get(mCurPos));
        } else {
            switchToHeader(onGetInitialHeader());
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //Persist our list and last clicked position
    if (mHeaders != null && mHeaders.size() > 0) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_CUR_HEADER_POS, mCurPos);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_HEADERS_LIST, mHeaders);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it still has one issue I've found. Suppose for simplicity multi-pane is true iff you are on landscape mode. Now run your app on portrait mode (single pane), choose a header, switch to landscape (multi-pane) and then switch to portrait mode. The issue is that the selected item is no longer restored. It just went back to the main settings screen, showing all headers. Not a big issue though. Just weird...

Answer (score 0):

The key idea behind the code below came from the Commonsware blog entry linked in the question, so it feels relevant. I specifically had to extend the concept to deal with an orientation change issue that sounds very similar to the one in the question, so here's hoping it gives you a start.

The Settings class should not have any bearing on the orientation issue, but including it anyway to be clear.

Per my code comment, see if the `checkNeedsResource` call in `onCreate` will help at all:

```
public class SettingsActivity
extends 
    PreferenceActivity
{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Show settings without headers for single pane or pre-Honeycomb. Make sure to check the
    // single pane or pre-Honeycomb condition again after orientation change.
    if (checkNeedsResource()) {
        MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_api);
        settings.setupPreference(findPreference(MyApp.KEY_USERNAME), prefs.getString(MyApp.KEY_USERNAME, null), true);
        settings.setupPreference(findPreference(MyApp.KEY_API_URL_ROOT), prefs.getString(MyApp.KEY_API_URL_ROOT, null), true);
        if (this.isHoneycomb) {
            // Do not delete this. We may yet have settings that only apply to Honeycomb or higher.
            //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_general);
        }
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_about);
        settings.setupPreference(findPreference(MyApp.KEY_VERSION_NAME), app.getVersionName());
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    super.onBuildHeaders(target);

    // This check will enable showing settings without headers for single pane or pre-Honeycomb. 
    if (!checkNeedsResource()) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}

private boolean checkNeedsResource() {
    // This check will enable showing settings without headers for single pane or pre-Honeycomb. 
    return (!this.isHoneycomb || onIsHidingHeaders() || !onIsMultiPane());
}

private boolean isHoneycomb = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);
```

}

```
public class Settings {

public Settings() {
}

public void setupPreference(Preference pref, String summary, boolean setChangeListener) {
    if (pref != null) {
        if (summary != null) {
            pref.setSummary(summary);
        }

        pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference pref, Object newValue) {
                pref.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}

public void setupPreference(Preference pref, String summary) {
    setupPreference(pref, summary, false);
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you posted here but this does not work. In fact, I'm not sure how this handles any orientation changes. I'm also not worried about anything before ICS, so none of that deprecated addPreferencesFromResource behavior is relevant to my question...nor is your preference changed listener.

Comment: The reason it resolved the issue I was running into is that check in onCreate, which occurs after an orientation change. That it did not help with the issue you were running into was more or less covered in my "here's hoping...". Glad you kept after it, and posted your resolution.